# "NoneType" attribute error when creating list of lists in Python

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe, nested-lists

So, I'm trying to create a list of lists that I can then use to create a new dataframe from, and before creating the dataframe, for each list, I want to append a name.

I've copied my code below ("stations" refers to a previously defined list of names of weather stations). Basically, I am iterating over this list, creating a temporary dataframe from the csv file, then cleaning the dataframe (the csv has a useless column and strings of "---" for missing values). The rest of the data is all numeric, and I had to create a dataframe using .astype() otherwise it read the data as strings.

To explain my final objective further, I aim to create a dataframe where each row contains the means of the columns for each station's data. I also want to add a new column at the end such that each row contains the name of the station it came from.

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
means = np.empty([5])
l = []

for j, station in enumerate(stations):
    temp = pd.read_csv('/Documents/data/' + station + 'data_clean.csv')
    temp = temp.drop('empty', axis=1).replace('---', np.nan)
    df = df.append(temp, ignore_index=True).astype({'tmax': np.float32,'tmin': np.float32,'af': np.float32,'rain': np.float32,'sun': np.float32})   

    # this line is to select the data for the spring months, then drop the (now unneeded) month and year columns
    df = df.loc[df['mm'].isin([3,4,5])].drop(['mm','yyyy'], axis=1)
    df = df.dropna()


    # Here, I am trying to create a list of the means for each column. 
    # Then I want to append this list to list l
    l1 = np.empty([5])
    for i, col in enumerate(list(df)):
        means[i] = df[col].mean()

    l2 = means.tolist()
    l = l.insert(j, l2)
    # I have also tried "l = l.append(l2)", which gave me the same error below

spring = pd.DataFrame(data=l)
```

When I run this, I get the following error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-80-227816ee4fc9> in <module>()
     15 
     16     l2 = means.tolist()
---> 17     l = l.insert(j,_list)
     18 
     19     spring = pd.DataFrame(data=l)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'insert'
```

My final output goal is a dataframe that looks like the following:

```
   tmax   tmin   af     rain   sun   station
0  mean0  mean0  mean0  mean0  mean0 station_name0
1  mean1  mean1  mean1  mean1  mean1 station_name1
2  mean2  mean2  mean2  mean2  mean2 station_name2
...
```

I'm currently stumped and would appreciate any ideas on how to fix this. I'd also appreciate any ideas on how to improve the code in general. Thanks in advance! I hope I've explained what I'm trying to do clearly enough.

Comment: You don't need to equate a list to a function, it should be `l.append(...)` or `l.insert(...)`

Comment: `list.append()` and `list.insert()` return `None`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`list.insert()` and `list.append()` modify the list in-place and return `None`. See this example:

```
>>> l = []
>>> print(l.insert(0, 'foo'))
None
>>> l
['foo']
>>> print(l.append('bar'))
None
>>> l
['foo', 'bar']
```